# Clear "unknown" characters from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, xfce4-terminal

```
set | grep TERM
TERM=xterm
    case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
        _rvm_old_traps=$( __rvm_grep -E 'EXIT|HUP|INT|QUIT|TERM' <(trap) );
        trap '__rvm_teardown_final ; set +x' EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM;
        trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM;
            case "${TERM:-dumb}" in

echo $TERM
xterm
```

in shell output i'm getting this strange character:`[3;J[H[2J` and few lines below desired output

Worth mentioning full code (it's powershell script running under linux)

```
#!/bin/bash
out=$(pwsh /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/1.ps1)
zabbix_sender -z localhost -p 10051 -s "London" -k status.azure -o "$out"
```

when adding this line `clear | hexdump`

i'm getting

```
0000000 5b1b 3b33 1b4a 485b 5b1b 4a32
000000c
```

How to clear this from output ?

`clear | od -bc` output:

```
0000000 033 133 063 073 112 033 133 110 033 133 062 112
        033   [   3   ;   J 033   [   H 033   [   2   J
0000014
```

Comment: output is :xterm

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by workaround:

-in powershell script redirected output to file

-in shell script added line for reading content of that file

-sending file content to zabbix

-no more strange symbols